# How to remove bundle product new and sale label in product list page

Tags: bundle, labels

I would like to remove bundle product new and sale label in product list page. How can i do that

Eg:
[image]

My code

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                <?php /* Based on the native RWD styling, product images are displayed at a max of ~400px wide when viewed on a
                        one column page layout with four product columns from a 1280px viewport. For bandwidth reasons,
                        we are going to serve a 300px image, as it will look fine at 400px and most of the times, the image
                        will be displayed at a smaller size (eg, if two column are being used or viewport is smaller than 1280px).
                        This $_imgSize value could even be decreased further, based on the page layout
                        (one column, two column, three column) and number of product columns. */ ?>
                <?php $_imgSize = 300; ?>
                <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                     src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                     alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
            </a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <div class="product-primary">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php
                            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                            foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
                                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                        ?>
                            <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-secondary">
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-secondary">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable() && !$_product->canConfigure()): ?>
                            <p class="action"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                        <?php elseif($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <p class="action"><a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a></p>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="action availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php /*if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
            <?php endif*/ ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                    <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                         src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                         alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>

                    <?php
                        $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                        foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
                            $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                            $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                    ?>
                        <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable() && !$_product->canConfigure()): ?>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php elseif($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php /*if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
            <?php endif*/ ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
    //set product collection on after blocks
    $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName):
        $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
        $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
    ?>
    <?php echo $_afterChild->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Please share your list.phtml code here

Comment: Sorry how can i share that file

Comment: Edit this question and just copy paste the code after or before the above image

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it is showing in your website.
There should be code in `/app/design/frontend/packagename/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` for show these label.
You need to just wrap that is inside this code:

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() != 'bundle' ) { ?>

<!-- Your label code should go here -->


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I want to remove that labels

Comment: @RameshS are you sure this is right file ? I' am unable to find the code for labels.Please enable template path hints an share right file

Comment: Thanks for replaying me @Arunendra. I done this work, i just command **CSS** `.lable-sale {display:none;}`. Now its working