# problems with label ON SALE

Tags: magento-2.1.7

When I put the new configurable product appear the label ON SALE but the product isn't on sale. How can I remove it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can get a reference from below link

[How to remove bundle product new and sale label in product list page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162980/how-to-remove-bundle-product-new-and-sale-label-in-product-list-page)

Hope this helps!

Comment: if my answer worked, you can accept it as answer!